# c++: Static variable defined in constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static-variables

I'm curious about what is really happening "under the hood" here. I'm creating a Class with an ID variable automatically assigned when the constructor is called, depending on how many instances have been created in the past.

**Class:**

```
class MyClass{
int ID;
public:
  MyClass(){
    static int id{1}; // Seems to be redefined every time the constructor is called.
    ID = id++;
  }
};
```

**Main**:

```
int main()
{
  MyClass a; // ID = 1
  MyClass b; // ID = 2
  MyClass c; // ID = 3
  return 0;
}
```

I'm only used to use static member variables that are initialized in the global scope (i.e. MyClass::staticVariable = 1), so this "in-class" initialization confuses me, as what is really happening.

**Is the static variable defined only the first time the line is run, and then ignored? Is this the general behaviour for any function AND member function?**

Comment: That's a [static local variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables).

Comment: That "top hit on google" does not explain precisely what is my confusion. I specifically asked for in-class initialization. Yes, It turns out to be the same behaviour as in a global-scope function, but that is exactly what I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all intents and purposes the behavior is the same as static member variables that are initialized at global scope, which you seem to grasp. The only difference I can see between the two is the scope, the static variable declared in the constructor is only avalilable at constructor scope, whereas a static variable declared as class member is, of course, avalilable at class scope, following the access rules, as all the ohters.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is a `static local variable`. Using the `static` keyword on a local
variable changes its duration from `automatic` duration to `static`
duration.

According to [cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables), the initialization is done the first time control passes through their declaration. On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

[Static local variables](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/static-local-variables/) and [lifetime-of-a-static-variable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-lifetime-of-a-static-variable-in-a-cplusplus-function#:%7E:text=A%20static%20variable%20is%20a,exists%20till%20the%20program%20executes.) are some interesting detailed articles.